# Program outputting strange characters even when the string is null-terminated

Tags: c, file

I am writing a program to read stdin and output it.

```
int main() {
    FILE* inputF = stdin;
    char* inputStr[10];

    fread(inputStr, 1, 9, inputF);
    if(ferror(inputF)) {
        printf("An error occurred");
        return 0;
    }

    inputStr[9] = '\0';

    printf("%s", (const char*)inputStr);

    return 0;
}
```

It should create a 10 character long string and read 9 bytes of stdin into it, and then put `'\0'` in position 9.

When I run the program, this is the result:

```
gab@testvm:~/work/c/fibo$ ./a.out < test.txt
56                                                                                                     `ô
                                                                                                       ga
```

Two lines and excess characters are printed (scroll to the right to see them).

What might be causing this?

Comment: Should I do that when I create the array?

Comment: @GabrieleCirulli Sorry, misread. (Fail.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DanielFischer has pointed out your immediate problem, however once you've fixed the `char[]` vs `char*[]` issue, you should also note...

If `test.txt` contains fewer than 9 characters then the you will still have junk characters between the last read character and the position where your write the null terminator.

You should check the return value of `fread` to see how many characters were read and write the null terminator in the appropriate place.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working fine now. As an alternative way, would it be possible to fill the string with '\0' before taking the input from stdin, so that the characters that remain are set to '\0'?

Comment: @GabrieleCirulli: Yes it would, but checking the return value is still a good idea. It will tell also you if the call failed.

Comment: Sure, `char inputStr[10] = {0};` does it.

Comment: Is it somehow bad practice to do so?

Answer (score 9):

`inputStr` is not a string,

```
char* inputStr[10];
```

it's an array of 10 `char *`. You should change the declaration to `char inputStr[10];`.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain to me when 'char *' should be used instead?

Comment: Actually, it looks as if it's still printing excess characters, even after changing the declaration of inputStr.

Comment: When you want to have a single string (or a pointer to one `char`). You could also have `char *inputStr = malloc(10);`, for example, in your code. Then you should `free(inputStr);` when you don't use it anymore.

Comment: When using `char inputStr[10]` I do not have to free any memory, right?

Comment: Correct, that's an automatic variable, usually allocated on the stack, it will be taken care of (if necessary) when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.
I've used this method to determine the place where I should put my null-termination character:

`readChars = fread(inputStr, 1, 9, inputF);`
and then
`inputStr[readChars - 1] = '\0';`. This way I get no excess characters because the string terminates at the right length.

Comment: You overwrite the last read character that way, it should be `inputStr[readChars] = 0;`.

Comment: You're right, but why is that? Isn't `readChars` an amount starting from 1? If I want to use that as an index shouldn't I subtract 1 to make it start from 0 as indexes do? Please excuse the prolonged discussion but I'd really like to understand the source of these problems.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6249/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-gabriele-cirulli)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    FILE* inputF = stdin;
    char inputStr[10];

    fread(inputStr, 1, 9, inputF);

    inputStr[9] = '\0';
    printf("%s \n", inputStr);

    return 0;
}

$ gcc run.c 
$ ./a.out 
123456789
123456789 
$
```

You need either a `char a[]` or `char *` but not `char *a[]`

The above code snippet is incomplete as it lacks error checking, input validation, etc.

Comment: I've added null termination in the right place as the above answers suggested, are there any more steps I should follow to make sure that the input is valid?

Comment: You should enter a valid char.. anything more than 9 will be ignored.. you may check the return value of the `fread()` function just in case.. other than that I guess you don't have to worry. If you think the above code have answered question, then please confirm so by clicking the tick mark next to the answer.. Thanks :)